# How to change ID?

Tags: tfs

Hallo experts,

i'm newbie to TFS, but responsible for SW Test in my group. I'm trying to create a couple of test cases thru MS Visual Studio. I don't know how to change the Test Case IDs, which seem to be automatically assigned by the system. However we want to adapt the IDs to the conventions in our SW specifications. Thanks in advance.

JohnMunich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's any way to do this within TFS itself.  These numbers are assigned and internally they are used as primary keys for the data.

You potentially could change the number that *will* be assigned.  I think [this](http://hinshlabs.codeplex.com/releases/view/54305) might be of help.

The problem is that this will change the next User Story ID that you generate, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Are you using this addon to apply customized Test Case ID to your project?

Comment: That's not what it does.  The IDs are assigned sequentially.  This just changes the start ID.  Like I said, I don't think it's possible to specify your own IDs.  What exactly is it that you're trying to achieve by not using standard numbering?

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a custom Test Case ID, you'll probably want to modify your work item template for the test cases with a new, custom field.

You can do this by exporting the appropriate work item type using the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx), adding the field and re-importing.

If you want the field to show up in the warehouse, be sure to make it reportable.

Note:  The direct link is for the TFS 2010 power tools.  This page also contains a link to the TFS 2008 Power Tools.